# How do I add a form on HTML and send to my email using PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

I am attempting to code a form on my HTML website with 5 fields and get them to send to my email using PHP. However, I am not sure why I am not able to successfully do that. I am able to get a positive feedback when I echo but when I add the `mailto()` part that's when everything gets complicated.

Would somebody be able to explain each step I will need to take in the procedure in creating a simple form using PHP from the very beginning. I would like to be able to use this for reference when coding forms – as well as anybody else that may need a reference.

Comment: Write me a reference, is a little off-topic for SO.  Try posting the code that is giving you problems.

Comment: I did but apparently if I post it its also off-topic... other pages don't seem to cover the source of my coding error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a basic email program that you can use:

```
$to = "person@example.com";
$subject = "Hello!";
$body = "Goodbye now. I am bored. Please give me pizza.";

mail($to, $subject, $body);
```

You just need those three parameters, and you can easily turn them into values from your form using this:

```
$to = $_POST["email"];
$subject = $_POST["email-subject"];
$body = $_POST["email-body"];
```

When the inputs in your form are this:

```
<input type="email" name="email" />
<input type="text" name="email-subject" />
<input type="text" name="email-body" />
```

You don't even need the `mailto()` mentioned in your question, just use this syntax:

```
mail(to, subject, message, headers, parameters);
```

And that's how you send an email in PHP.